# prove that $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(k-1)!a_{n-k}\rightarrow a_n=n!$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I try to prove that:
Given $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(k-1)!a_{n-k},a_0 = a_1 = 1$. Prove that $a_n=n!$ for any natural $n$, by finding a combinatorics problem that fits both. any solution (combinatorial proofs)?

Comment: $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(k-1)!a_{n-k},a_1=1,a_0=1\rightarrow a_n=n!$ really doesn't make sense. Moreover, induction proof should work !

Comment: what doesn't make any sense? this identity is right. you can check it.

Comment: Maybe it make sense for you, but not for me ! What does mean $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(k-1)!a_{n-k},a_1=1,a_0=1\rightarrow a_n=n!$ ? is it a limit ?

Comment: if n is 0, then a_n is 1. if n is 1, then a_n is 1. if n is natural and greater than 1, it is the formula with the sum. The identity claims, that the general formula of a_n is exactly n!

Comment: make sense now?

Comment: Not for me ! But I guess that you mean "Let $(a_n)$ defined by $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1}(k-1)!a_{n-k}$$ where $a_0=a_1=1$. Prove that $a_n=n!$. And as I told you with my first comment, induction proof should work.

Comment: yeah this is exactly what I mean. I'm looking for a combinatorial-proof.

Answer (score 1):

We'll show by induction that $a_n$ is the number of permutations of $n$ elements, and it'll follow from this that $a_n = n!$.

Base: $a_0 = a_1 = 1$ is indeed the number of permutations of 0 and 1 elements respectively.

Assume $a_t$ is the number of permutations of $t$ elements for all $t < l$. Then we'll prove that $a_l$ is the number of permutations of $l$ elements.

Assume we're permuting the numbers from 1 to $n$. First, we can choose any position for the number $1$. If 1 is in position $k$, we need choose the $k-1$ from the remaining $n-1$ numbers to come before it, and we have $(k-1)!$ ways to order them. We're left with $n-k$ numbers that we ween to place after the 1, and we can do that in $(n-k)! = a_{n-k}$ ways (by induction hypothesis). Thus, we have a total of
$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n - 1 \choose k - 1}(k-1)!a_{n-k}$$
ways to permute $n$ numbers. By definition, this is $a_n$.

Comment: sorry, I wish a combinatorial-proof

Comment: @proven What is not combinatorial about this?

Comment: Combinatorial proofs of identities use double counting and combinatorial characterizations of binomial coefficients, powers, factorials etc.

Comment: @proven This is double counting of permutations. If your issue is with induction, I don't think it's avoidable, because the sequence is recurrent. Pretty much the only way to formally prove something about it is induction (or theorems that have themselves been proved using induction).